# Using Alamofire in UI Test Target

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode-ui-testing

The below code snippet using Alamofire works fine in iOS app but the code does not work in iOS UI Testing target.

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders =   Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders
manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
manager!.request(.GET, "https://www.google.com")
        .responseString { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            print("HTML: \(response.result.value)")
    }
```

The completion handler never gets invoked in UI Testing target.

If I add .progress block to request, that is getting executed, but the completionHandler still does not get executed.

Can someone please shed light on what I might be doing wrong.